# OpenPyxl accessing number_format

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using the openpyxl library to read an excel file.

The Excel file contains some cells with dollar values in them.

When I access these cells, openpyxl will return integers.

```
data = worksheet["G"][7].value #The type of "data" will be integer.
```

Now, I understand that most of the time, returning an integer is desirable. But each cell also has a variable "number_format" associated with it that contains things like the dollar signs, commas, and percent markings in a cell's value.

So far as I can tell, openpyxl's documentation does not say anything about getting a cell value simply as a string, with the "number_format" applied to it.

I don't particularly want to write my own parser for the number_format code. That sounds like reinventing the wheel. I feel like there should be a simple solution to this but I have yet to find one. If anyone knows a solution to this your input is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The values in the cells are numbers and this is what openpyxl returns: "$2.45" is meaningless in Python. We only convert dates and times based upon their number formats. If you want to do anything else then you will need to write your own parser for the OOXML number format.

Comment: I fully understand that an integer is often more useful than a string for a value like "$2.45". I was just hoping openpyxl provided the /option/ to access this as a string so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel writing my own parser. I take it that this is not an option, so I guess I will indeed have to write one, or find a suitable library for it.